# Dynamic radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a page full of radio buttons and it won't display "Success: You have completed all questions" dynamically.

html:

```
    Question 1:<br />
    <label><input name="income" type="radio" value="1"  />10,000</label> <br />
    <label><input name="income" type="radio" value="3" />30,000</label> <br />
    <label><input name="income" type="radio" value="5" />50,000</label> <br />

    Question 2:<br />
    <label><input name="debt" type="radio" value="1" />10,000</label> <br />
    <label><input name="debt" type="radio" value="5" />50,000</label> <br />
    <label><input name="debt" type="radio" value="10" />10,000</label> <br />

    <div id="display">0</div>
```

script:

```
$('#display').each(function(){
    if($(':radio[name=income]:checked, :radio[name=debt]:checked').length == 2)
    $("#display").html('<p>Success: You have completed all questions</p>');
    else
    $("#display").html('<p>You have NOT yet completed all questions</p>');
});
```

Thank if you can help.

http://jsfiddle.net/C7NmD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the code to an event listener. Currently, you're running the code only once, at page load. After binding an event listener (`change`), the code will run at each `input[type=radio]` state change. see http://jsfiddle.net/C7NmD/1/

```
$(":radio").change(function(){
    $('#display').each(function(){
        if($(':radio[name=income]:checked, :radio[name=debt]:checked').length == 2)
            $("#display").html('<p>Success: You have completed all questions</p>');
        else
            $("#display").html('<p>You have NOT yet completed all questions</p>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understood correctly.. You don't need that much code..
Try the below code..

```
 $('input').live('change',function()
 {
   if($(':radio:checked').size() > 1) // One is number of Questions-1 in your case..
   {
     $('#display').html('Answered all.')   
   }
 });
```

Because only one answer is possible for each group of radio buttons you just check the checked radio buttons size..
Here is the working fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/C7NmD/4/
```

Comment: Even simpler, thanks 100. I didn't realise just how much you could do with so little code.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest an adaptation to your mark-up that should make it easier to implement this functionality? Containing each of your questions in an element, in my suggestion a `fieldset`, allows you to increase the number of questions without having to manually list each and every `:radio[name="radioName"]`:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Question 1:</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="income" />10,000</label> <br />
    <label><input name="income" type="radio" value="3" />30,000</label> <br />
    <label><input name="income" type="radio" value="5" />50,000</label> <br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Question 2:</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="debt" />10,000</label> <br />
    <label><input name="debt" type="radio" value="5" />50,000</label> <br />
    <label><input type="radio" value="10" name="debt" />10,000</label> <br />
</fieldset>

<div id="display">0</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('input:radio').click(
    function() {
        var q = $('fieldset').length;
        console.log('q: ' + q + '; checked: ' + $('input:radio:checked').length);
        if ($('input:radio:checked').length == q){
            $('#display').text('Congratulations! You\'ve completed all questions!');
        }
        else {
            $('#display').text('You\'ve not yet finished...');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/C7NmD/9/).

Comment: Thanks David, I have not heard of fieldset before, that was a neat way of doing it.

Comment: You're very welcome! Bear in mind that should you use `fieldset`s to contain other elements of the form (submit/reset buttons, user's name or whatever) that you'll have to distinguish between those fieldsets containing questions and those containing other information (so it might be wiser to use `<fieldset class="questions">` and `var q = $('fieldset.questions').length;`), but it depends on your use-case, really.